# Tab event changes the focus even after focus is set in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input elements, one a text box and the next one a drop down list(ddl) side by side in a HTML page. The user is supposed to enter a value greater than 5 (its just an example) and then select an item from the ddl.

I have written a validation that happens whenever there is a change in the text box. If the value is not greater than 5, then the user is informed the value should be greater than 5 and the focus is set to the text box. (I am using Jquery)

```
$(".textBox").change( function(){
  alert("Quantity should be greater than 5");
  $(this).val("");
  $(this).focus();  
}
```

Now here is the problem,

Case 1:
When the user enters a value below 5 and presses tab logically the focus should come back to the textbox after the alert, but the focus seems to have moved to the dropdown list.

Case 2:
When the user enters a value below 5 and clicks on the dropdown list, there is an alert message, but instead of the focus being in the text box, the drop down list has expanded.

I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it so that if the value is less than 5 then the focus should be on the text box.

Any help is appreciated.
nJ

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the default behaviour of the tab key press by adding the following code

```
$("#txtBox").keydown(function(event){
  if($("#txtBox").val()<5)
    {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) 
    event.preventDefault();

    }
})
```

Comment: So why is the focus() overridden? Also val()>5 is not the logic, its just an example, the real logic much more complex(it has to do an ajax postback.

Comment: It is overriden becasue after the text change event is completed, tab key press event is fired. it is event bubbling